# does illustrator or photoshop change the dpi, ppi or alpha when using transparency?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, transparency, ppi

I was enjoying the use of different transparency settings in both programs and was wondering if the simulated transparency would have any effect on the use of the images in different production environments(web and print)?

Comment: Transparency and alpha has nothing to do with resolution.

Comment: In addition to Rafael's comment.. alpha **is** transparency, so that part of your question is rather confusing.

Comment: The only effect I could imagine would be varying file sizes (negligible) and low/no support in versions of IE that you should not be supporting anyway (i.e below version 8). It will not impact resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer: It depends ;)

Apart from your confusion between alpha and pixel density,
The possibilities are quite vast so there is no real answer.
It depends on many things like which color profile is used and if you have a consistent color setting in your programs.

In web the big fun begins when you realize that not al browsers support color profiles.

So there is only one real solution: Test it yourself.